# Automatically Trim City Off of a Store Code

Tags: apex

I'm attempting to remove the store from my referral store number and was curious if anyone had any experience trimming anything after a space in a variable. For example I have a variable that equals Chicago 1111. I want to be able to automatically trim chicago off of the variable no matter how long the numbers are.

I currently am trying this.

```
String Ref = a.Referral_Store__c;

  if (a.Referral_Store__c != null) {
 Ref = a.Referral_Store__c.substringAfter(' ');
  }
```

However I'm getting the error

> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please **[edit]** this post to include include any attempts you have made and expected input/output combos.

Comment: @AdrianLarson There, I updated my post using your suggestion and revised the order of the city and number as I had typed them in reverse. However, I'm getting a null object error.

Comment: As written, the only place where you're capable of throwing the null pointer exception is if `a` is null when you're referencing `Referral_Store__c` from it.

Comment: @MarkPond Alright, great, I'll hunt through the code and see what I can find. Possible that it is just above the initiation of a.

Comment: Change your if statement to: `if (a!= null && a.Referral_Store__c != null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove everything after the first occurrence of a specific character, I recommend using `substringBefore`:

```
String beforeFirstSpace = someInput.substringBefore(' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

A string replace should do the trick:

```
String s = myString.replace('Chicago','');
```

You could also try something like this (for case insensitivity):

```
var endIndex = myString.indexOfIgnoreCase('Chicago');
String s = myString.substring(0, endIndex-1);
```

Comment: I think this might just work... I have a variable with each store location and should be able to put that variable where Chicago is and then replace it. Thanks so much, again.  I'll let you know what I come up with.